# Best practice to avoid conflict with user supplied variable names - R

Tags: r, function, variables, scope

I'm trying to create a R function for a package that will take user data and (the right hand side of) a formula, do some processing, and return a model. But, I'm having trouble when the user data or formula contain variables with the same name as I use internally. A reproducible example,

(Note that updating the formula's environment is required to keep R from looking in the user's R_GlobalEnv for my variable y.)

```
# R Version 3.6.2
my_function <- function(user_data, user_formula){
  y <- as.numeric(user_data[,1] > mean(user_data[,1]))

  my_formula <- update.formula(user_formula, y ~ .)
  environment(my_formula) <- environment()

  my_model <- lm(my_formula, data = user_data, model = TRUE)
  return(my_model)
}

some_data <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,3))
some_formula <- response ~ x1
my_function(some_data, some_formula)
```

The above is what I want to run, and it works as long as there isn't variable in user_formula or user_data with the name "y". But when the user_data contains a variable with the same name, the model will use that variable instead of mine.

```
some_data <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,3), y = c(6,7,5,6))
some_formula <- response ~ x1 + y
my_function(some_data, some_formula)$model
#   y x1
# 1 6  1
# 2 7  2
# 3 5  3
# 4 6  3
# Warning messages:
# 1: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
#   the response appeared on the right-hand side and was dropped
# 2: In model.matrix.default(mt, mf, contrasts) :
#   problem with term 2 in model.matrix: no columns are assigned
```

I tried forcing R to search the function's environment for y by using get(),

```
my_function <- function(user_data, user_formula){
  y <- as.numeric(user_data[,1] > mean(user_data[,1]))

  e1 <- environment()
  my_formula <- update.formula(user_formula, get("y", e1) ~ .)
  environment(my_formula) <- environment()

  my_model <- lm(my_formula, data = user_data, model = TRUE)
  return(my_model)
}

some_data <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,3), y = c(6,7,5,6))
some_formula <- response ~ x1 + y
my_function(some_data, some_formula)$model
#   get("y", e1) x1 y
# 1            0  1 6
# 2            0  2 7
# 3            1  3 5
# 4            1  3 6
```

But this also fails if the user data has a variable with the same name as my internal environment name,

```
some_data <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,3), y = c(6,7,5,6), e1 = c(1,2,3,4))
some_formula <- response ~ x1 + y + e1
my_function(some_data, some_formula)$model
#  Error in get("y", e1) : invalid 'envir' argument
```

What is the proper way to avoid overlapping my internal variables with user-supplied variable names? I'd prefer a method for base R if possible.

Comment: What is your desired result of both those function calls, particular what formula do you want for second call? Do you want *y* on both sides of regression equation?

Comment: @Parfait I want my y on the left-hand and any user-supplied variables on the right-hand side, including their y if they define it. How can I define my variable so it won't conflict with any of theirs, no matter what they submit?

Comment: @Parfait the broader context of this question is that I'm using the model from my_function to update the model from the user's specification. The model lm(user_formula, user_data) is updated based on lm(my_response ~ user_covariates, user_data). I want to take user_response as the main analysis response, but also calculate my_response and use that to fit another model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/lm) of **`lm`**, the *data* argument handles variables in formula in two ways that are NOT mutually exclusive:

> **data** 
>       an optional data frame, list or environment (or object coercible by `as.data.frame` to a data frame) containing the variables in the model. If not found in `data`, the variables are taken from `environment(formula)`, typically the environment from which `lm` is called.

Specifically, the calculated *y* vector in function runs into a name collision with potential *y* column in data frame. As you noticed and as emphasized in docs above, `lm` will default to *y* column before the *y* vector.

To avoid naming conflict, consider adding a suitable placeholder like *response* or *dependent_variable* and raise a `tryCatch` warning if user supply a data frame with same column name. This approach also allows you to avoid resetting the `environment(formula)`.

```
my_function <- function(user_data, user_formula){
  tryCatch({
       user_data$response <- as.numeric(user_data[,1] > mean(user_data[,1]))

       my_formula <- update.formula(user_formula, response ~ .)

       my_model <- lm(my_formula, data = user_data, model = TRUE)

       return(my_model)
  }, warning = function(w) message("Please rename column 'response' in your data frame")
   , error = function(e) print(e)
  )
}
```

**Output**

```
some_data <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,3))
some_formula <- response ~ x1
my_function(some_data, some_formula)

# Call:
# lm(formula = my_formula, data = user_data, model = TRUE)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x1  
#     -0.7273       0.5455  

some_data <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,3), y = c(6,7,5,6), e1 = c(1,2,3,4))
some_formula <- response ~ x1 + y + e1
my_function(some_data, some_formula)

# Call:
# lm(formula = my_formula, data = user_data, model = TRUE)

# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           x1            y           e1  
#   1.667e+00    3.850e-16   -3.333e-01    3.333e-01  

some_data <- data.frame(x1 = c(1,2,3,3), y = c(6,7,5,6), response=c(1,1,1,1))
some_formula <- response ~ x1 + y + response
my_function(some_data, some_formula)
# Please rename column 'response' in your data frame
```

Comment: "To avoid naming conflict, simply add a column with a name users would never consider giving" is probably good practical advice but it still bothers me. It also may conflict with advice to have informative variable names. I can add a check for whether they define a column with my name and throw an error if they do, so if there isn't another way to do it I'll accept this answer. I'd still prefer a more principled method if one exists.

Comment: My first answer was just to use a generic name like *response*. But checking names is appropriate. See edit wrapping function in `tryCatch` and raising a message with warning. Notice, too, *response* never shows up in regression output. Adjust to a more legitimate name per your domain or needs.

Comment: Also, with fuller context of your situation, a different process can be recommended as it is unclear why users cannot supply their own response variable in formula.